# Большинство изложения

Tags: семантика

Употребляется ли слово "большинство" в значении "большая часть"? Например: *большинство изложения.*

Answer (score 1):

В Большом толковом словаре  значение слова "большинство": *"Большая часть, большее число"*.

Тем не менее, насколько я понимаю, "большинство" используется в значении **"бо́льшая часть какой-либо группы"**, а не "большая часть неисчисляемого целого". То есть *большинство морей*, но *бо́льшая часть воды*. *Большинство банков*, но *бо́льшая часть денег*.

Comment: Встречал: большинство народа

Comment: Да, я тоже встречал, а также "большинство населения", "большинство элиты" и проч. И это, по-видимому, не противоречит словарному определению. У Ефремовой вообще: "Большинство — бОльшая часть чего-либо целого, какой-либо группы предметов". Но если посмотреть Нацкорпус, то преобладает именно "большинство" как "бОльшая часть какой-либо группы". Мне кажется, что "большинство народа" и аналогичные сочетания звучат и по-канцелярски, и разговорно, и по-журналистски одновременно.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, не употребляется, насколько я знаю.